# Google star rating for game

Tags: seo, google-search

Hello i have a site with flash games and i need to add star rating for each game in google search like for amazon ['here'](https://www.google.com/search?q=laptop%20amazon&oq=laptop%20amazon&aqs=chrome..69i57.3875j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=amazon%20smartphone%20iphone) but without review just rating its possible ? google dont punish me for that because its not an article ?

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    Rated: <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/<span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
</div>
```

I tested the code here https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ but i have error

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a valid code (not related to games, but you'll get the idea). You could test it in the tool:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> stars -
Based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">250</span> reviews
</div>
</div>
```

Now, you can't really put whatever you want there. In order to use the star rating you have to put `reviewCount` or `ratingCount`. Those are just mandatory.

Comment: that isn't complete enough to work, the min and max values for possible ratings are needed so the snippet can say 4/5 stars for instance. Otherwise the star icons don't appear

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems coming up from the tester

- it doesn't know what Thing you are rating, you need to tell it you are rating a game,  and what the game is called
- you gave a best rating but no ratingCount, how many people rated it? If you don't know set to '1' and use a `<meta>` tag to hide this

Use this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoGame">
   <a href="http://example.com/supergame1" itemprop="url">Download</a>
   <img alt="Super Game logo" src="/images/screenshots/supergame/cover.jpg"/>

   <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    Rated: <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/<span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
    Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">1</span> rating(s).
   </div>

</div>
```

The page http://schema.org/VideoGame has more examples, and google may ask for a few more properties like `name` or `headline` for the game. Google can suddenly decide things are compulsory when they were not last month.